# Is there a reason to prefer the `nobuild` and `configuration` inputs vs using arguments in the DotNetCoreCLI@2 Azure pipeline task?

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

The `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task in Azure Pipelines has specific inputs that seem to translate to equivalent MSBuild arguments one would pass when manually running commands like `dotnet test ...`

When looking at samples in articles, I ALMOST NEVER see anyone using the task inputs, and always using arguments.
However, when I read the [docs for that task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops), it seems to imply that the inputs are equivalent to using the respective arguments.

Also, when I run the pipeline with diagnostics enabled, and I inspect the line that issues the `dotnet [command]` in the build agent, it doesn't seem to be adding the equivalent arguments to the `dotnet` cli command when I only use the task inputs vs. manually adding the arguments.

Are these 2 equivalent and should I favor one over the other (if so, why)?

Example using task inputs:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Run All Tests'
    inputs:
      command: 'test'
      projects: 'portal/tests/**/*.csproj'
      testRunTitle: 'Merge CI Build: All Tests - #$(Build.BuildId)'
      configuration: $(buildConfiguration) #<--------- THIS
      nobuild: true #<--------- THIS
      publishTestResults: true
```

Example using only arguments:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Run All Tests'
    inputs:
      command: 'test'
      projects: 'portal/tests/**/*.csproj'
      testRunTitle: 'Merge CI Build: All Tests - #$(Build.BuildId)'
      publishTestResults: true
      arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --no-build'
```

**[UPDATE with more details]**

Here's what I see from the task execution in Azure pipelines when it executes the `dotnet test` command while using the task inputs, instead of the arguments:

```
/usr/bin/dotnet test /home/vsts/work/1/s/portal/tests/MyApp.UnitTests/MyApp.UnitTests.csproj --logger trx --results-directory /home/vsts/work/_temp
```

Comment: What arguments are you seeing appended to `dotnet` in the diagnostics? You mention that they’re different, but only show the YML, not the `dotnet` command being executed. I’d be pretty shocked if these weren’t equivalent. FWIW: I use the task arguments when available, just because I prefer having them explicitly enumerated, as opposed to being concatenated via the `arguments` property. But it shouldn’t ultimately matter, but should instead be matter of personal preference.

Comment: when I use the task inputs, I DO NOT see the `--no-build` nor the `--configuration` arguments appended to the `dotnet test` command.

I'll edit the question to include this extra detail.